# Setting the property `tabBarActiveTintColor` in `Tab.Navigator` does not work

Tags: react-native

```js
function MyTabs() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName='Home'
            screenOptions={{
                tabBarActiveTintColor: 'purple',
            }}
         >
             <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
             <Tab.Screen name='Settings' component={SettingsScreen} />
         </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

I have no idea why this property just doesn't change color, already tried to launch it on android, ios and web.
But they always keep the default colors, I also checked that it was well written but it still doesn't change the color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `tabBarActiveTintColor` and `tabBarInactiveTintColor` provide the colors for the `tabBarIcon` and `tabBarLabel` which we can specify in the `options` prop of `Tab.screen`. You haven't specified that.

Consider the following code snippet.

```js
<Tab.Screen name="Home" options={{
    tabBarLabel: (props) => <Text style={{ color: props.color}}>Home</Text>,
    tabBarIcon: (props) => do the same for your icon
 }}
 component={HomeScreen}
/>
```

Whenever the tab `Home` is selected the color in `props` is the one specified in `tabBarActiveTintColor` and `tabBarInactiveTintColor` otherwise. The same holds for all tabs specified in the Tab.Navigator.

It might be advised to create a custom Tab-Bar-Component, that is any react-native component that represents your custom tab bar object (including icon, text and styling).

If you want to color the whole tab bar, then we need to provide the `tabBarStyle` prop to the `Tab.Navigator`. Consider the following code snippet.

```js
<Tab.Navigator
    tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "red",
    }
...
</Tab.Navigator>
```